# Importing linprog module from scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to solve a linear program with SciPy. I import what I assume to be the relevant module with the line:

```
import scipy.optimize.linprog
```

Then, I run the solver with:

```
scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A, b)
```

The given error states

```
ImportError: No module named linprog
```

It appears that most errors like this occur when people do not specify the module to import. However, I think that I have done that by specifying linprog. Any advice?

EDIT:

The import line has been modified to:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
```

Now the error states: ImportError: cannot import name linprog
I have scipy version 0.13.0b1, and have been unable to find a way to update it.

Comment: Try this: `from scipy.optimize import linprog`

Comment: That results in an invalid syntax error. The error occurs at the t in import, it says..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have scipy version `0.15.0` or above.

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
linprog(c, A, b)
```

Comment: I have version 0.13.0b1, apparently. Do you have any advice on an easy way to upgrade?

Comment: I just tried to run: "sudo pip install --upgrade scipy". However, there was an error about not finding a Fortran compiler

Comment: I have version 0.15.1 and the file _linprog.py is also existing under optimize in scipy folder but I am not able to import linprog :/ PATH has the python site-packages in it.